# software screen disappears when i click to open a dialog box in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a WPF applicaton. when i click the button from my main screen of software or the shell UI to open a Dialog box the software screen disappears and it shows me the screen of previous process that i have opened before using the software screen like the code or explorer. and then to go to the screen i have to click the software from task bar.
this is the code to show this dialog box.

public void ShowView()
        {

```
        this.Owner = (Window)Shell;
        this.ShowDialog();            

    }
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you would provide more specifics. What code runs when you click your button? How does the data binding look?

Comment: Some code would be helpful....

Answer (score 0):

Your dialog must be set with an owner window and should be opened dispatched on UI thread of the owner.

```
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
         new Action(
             () =>
                 { 
                   DialogWindow.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
                   DialogWindow.ShowDialog();
                 } ));
```

Does this help?